# Is /boot/efi/EFI/ on Ubuntu the same location as the System Partition/EFI on Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, efi

I have a dual boot installation of Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and when I use `diskpart` to assign a drive letter to the `EFI System Partition` in Windows and I explore it, it contains the same files and folders as the `/boot/efi/EFI/` folder in my Ubuntu file manager. This led me to believing these two are the same location, but the ubuntu folder is located on another partition entirely, so I'm not completely sure. Is Ubuntu using Symbolic/Soft links and are these truly the same location, or are they two different things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both locations show you the same partition.

Linux uses a "virtual file system" model – instead of each partition having its own root (drive letter), there's only a single root (the `/`) and partitions are allowed to be mounted at *any* location under that. So while you have the main Ubuntu partition mounted at `/`, there can be a different partition assigned to `/boot/efi`.

(Similarly, it is very common to make /home a separate partition. And when you connect a random USB stick, it will be under `/run/media/Conner` or something such.)

These *mount points* are not symlinks, because a symlink would still need to point to some other path as its target – a mount point makes the path exist in the first place.

Run `findmnt` or `lsblk -f` to see which partitions are mounted where. (Note that findmnt will also show you a ton of *virtual* filesystems not corresponding to any physical disk or partition, but it gives you a good overview of what the VFS actually looks like.)